# Can be define a text value present in excel cell as variable name in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I pretty new to VBA. Actually my scenario is little complex to elaborate, so let me start with an example and explain to you what exactly I need. I will be having three worksheets in excel.

1. Base Sheet
2. Condition Sheet
3. Destination Sheet

Base sheet will be in the below format:

```
             Column A    Column B   Column C    Column D
Row1    Some text1    Some text2    Some text3  SETA
Row2    Some text4    Some text5    Some text6  
Row3    Some text7    Some text8    Some text9  
Row4    Some text10   Some text11   Some text12 SETB
Row5    Some text13   Some text14   Some text15 
Row6    Some text16   Some text17   Some text18 SETC
Row7    Some text19   Some text20   Some text21 
Row8    Some text22   Some text23   Some text24 
Row9    Some text25   Some text26   Some text27
```

As you see in the above example. It's showing that first 3 rows are for "SETA", next 2 rows are of "SETB" and next 4 rows are of "SETC".  Here in this sheet (BASE sheet) the column number will be constant, so every time we will be having 4 columns, but the number of rows in each SET and also number of SETs are variable.  Different users can enter different data in to this worksheet.

Worksheet 2 - Condition sheet will be having multiple rows with 3 constant columns, as shown below.

```
        Column A        Column B        Column C
Row1    SETA                10         Replace text
Row2    SETB                 5         Replace text
Row3    SETC                 6         Replace text
```

My last worksheet will have an ActiveX button, so when I click that button:

- The macro will first look in to the first row of (Condition Sheet), which means use "SETA" in (Base sheet).
- Copy the "SETA" data
- Paste in 10 times in destination sheet and then replace some
  text.
- Then the 2nd row (Condition Sheet), now it uses SETB in Base sheet copy the SETB
  data and paste in 5 times in destination sheet and then replace some
  text.
- Likewise, it increments until last row.

I got the code for this, I am able to successfully achieve what I need. The problem is it's predefined, so every time I need to look into (Base Worksheet) and count how many SET's are there, and how many rows each SET has, then I need to declare it as follows.

```
Dim seta As Range
Dim setb As Range
Dim setc As Range   
Set seta = Sheet1.Range("A1:C3")
Set setb = Sheet1.Range("A4:C5")
Set setc = Sheet1.Range("A6:C9")
```

Can it be user defined? I mean when a user enters the data in Base sheet with multiple SET's and multiple rows in each SET.  VBA should count how many SET's are there and how many rows in each SET and it should dynamically declare "seta","setb","setc",etc., as range objects.

I know it very long and confusing but kindly ignore my poor questionnaire skills and let me know if any further info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the set changes automatically, and not let the user define them.

Take a look at this code:

```
Option Base 1
Dim sets(3) As Range,i as Integer,row as Integer,set_row as Integer
row =1
set_row=1
i=1
While ((Range("A" & row)<>"") And (i<=3))
    If ((Range("D" & row) <> Range("D" & set_row)) And (Range("D" & row)<>"")) Then
        Set sets(i)=Sheet1.Range("A"& set_row &":C" & (row-1))
        set_row=row
        i=i+1
    End If
    row=row+1
Wend
```

Comment: hi Goren, thanks for the code. i tried using your code but its getting run time error 424 - object required. below is the code assigned to my Activex button:

Comment: Dim sets(3) As Range, i As Integer, row As Integer, set_row As      Integer
    row = 1
    set_row = 1
    i = 1
    While ((Range("A" & row) <> "") And (i <= 3))
    If ((Range("D" & row) <> Range("D" & set_row)) And (Range("D" & row) <> "")) Then
        Set sets(i) = Sheet1.Range("A" & set_row & ":C" & (row - 1))
        set_row = row
        i = i + 1
    End If
    row = row + 1
    Wend
    sets1.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet1").Range("N1")
    End Sub

Comment: On what line are you getting the `object required` error ?

Comment: sets1.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet1").Range("N1")                  on this line.. this is only line i added to test the code. i am trying to copy paste the first set. but i am getting this error :(

Comment: i got the issue, its sets(1) not sets1. :)

Comment: Right, I used an array in my code snippet and not 3 variables, please accept the answer or at least vote-up if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which you can pass the set name to, and it will return the range for that set (assuming the name is found in ColD)

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, s As String

    s = "SETB"
    Set rng = GetSetRange(s)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print s & " = " & rng.Address(False, False)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Set '" & s & "' not found!"
    End If

End Sub



Function GetSetRange(setName As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, f As Range, sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Base Sheet")
    Set f = sht.Columns(4).Find(setName, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Set rv = f.EntireRow.Cells(1).Resize(1, 3)
        i = 1
        Do While Application.CountA(rv.Offset(i, 0)) > 0 And _
                 Len(f.Offset(i, 0)) = 0
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        Set rv = rv.Resize(i, 3)
    End If
    Set GetSetRange = rv
End Function
```